# Display multiple UIViewControllers in Storyboard by implementing codes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

More specific,

Let's say I have a `UIViewController` **A**, when I press a `button` in **A** that is created by code, I would like to display another `UIViewController` **B**, where *B* is designed in the `storyboard`. Can it be done by coding, but not using the connections between `view controllers` in the `storyboard`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely,

Make sure you have added the storyBoardIdentifier to ViewController B.

Finally, In your ViewController A :

```
let YourStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
let vc = YourStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCB_StoryBoard_Identifier") as! ViewControllerB
```

If your ViewController has a UINavigationController embedded to it then,

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Else present ViewController B from ViewController A

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT:**

Set your storyboard identifier as shown in image below
[image]

Associate your ViewControllerB class with storyboard VC by setting the ViewController's class. As shown below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, how can I declare the "ViewControllerB"

Comment: I type the name in the Identity : storyboard ID in the storyboard view, then I try to type the same name in the following code

let vc = YourStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCB_StoryBoard_Identifier") as! ABCD

but it shows that ABCD is undeclared

Comment: after i successfully do it, it says the new view is not in the window hierarchy. how can i solve it

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a new cocoa touch class -> UIViewController -> "ViewContollerB"

Add the name in the storyboard to the view and than you can do:

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoard", bundle: nil)

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCB_StoryBoard_Identifier") as! ViewContollerB

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On button tap in `UIViewController` **`A`**,

```
func onTapButton()
{
    let controller = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerBIdentifier") as! ViewControllerB
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here,

`ViewControllerBIdentifier` : `StoryboardID` corresponding to `UIViewController` **`B`**

`ViewControllerB` : `class` corresponding to `UIViewController` **`B`**

Comment: Attempt to present <B> on <A> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

How to solve this problem? thanks.